# Unable to understand lines of javascript

Tags: javascript

I am unable to understand a small code piece of JavaScript.
Please help me to know the meaning of the following JavaScript blocks:

```
x = 2 + a / 30 >> 0;
```

What is the meaning of ">>" in JavaScript?

```
D = !0;
```

What is the value of D?

Comment: Format your code... people would have hard time understanding your code than you.

Comment: `What is value of D?` Have you tried running it? http://jsfiddle.net/7JXFs/

Comment: `D = !0;` can easily be run using jsfiddle as @apsillers suggests, or just in console of your browser... (ctrl+shift+k in firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only JavaScript it is Shift operator generic to almost all programming languages..

[`Here`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx) is a link:

Example: 5 << 1  becomes 10..

(0101)b becomes (1010)b .. ie, 10 in decimal system